# How to mock Picker and Picker.Item with jest in React-Native?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to snapshot test this snippet of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Picker,
} from 'react-native';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={this.props.asset.type}
        onValueChange={this.props.onTypeChange}>
        <Picker.Item label="Type of asset" value="default" />
        <Picker.Item label="Car" value="car" />
        <Picker.Item label="Boat" value="boat" />
        <Picker.Item label="Ship" value="ship" />
      </Picker>
    );
  }
}
```

My test looks like this right now:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  const asset = {
    type: 'car',
  }
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <TestComponent 
        asset={asset} />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
})
```

My problem is that I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_tag' of undefined
```

I think that I should mock it based on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1384)

I have tried adding simply:

```
jest.mock('Picker', () => 'Picker')
```

But than it still throws an error because Picker.Item is still not mocked

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-
in components) or a class/function (for composite components) 
but got: undefined. Check the render method of `TestComponent`.
```

Other variants I tried with no avail:

```
jest.mock('Picker', () => {return {Item: 'Item'}});
----------------------------------------------------
class Picker{
  Item = 'PickerItem'
}
jest.mock('Picker', () => {
  return Picker;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Created a [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1960) as well and here is a working answer:

```
jest.mock('Picker', () => {
  const Picker = class extends Component {
    static Item = props => React.createElement('Item', props, props.children);
    static propTypes = { children: React.PropTypes.any };

    render() {
      return React.createElement('Picker', this.props, this.props.children);
    }
  }
  return Picker;
})
```

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#tips

Comment: Is there a way to pass the event.type into the fireEvent onChange method?

Answer (score 2):

For Expo v39, I was able to test `@react-native-community/picker` by adding the following mock to my test/setup file:

```
jest.mock('@react-native-community/picker', () => {
  const React = require('React')
  const RealComponent = jest.requireActual('@react-native-community/picker')

  class Picker extends React.Component {
    static Item = (props: { children: never }) => {
      return React.createElement('Item', props, props.children)
    }

    render () {
      return React.createElement('Picker', this.props, this.props.children)
    }
  }

  Picker.propTypes = RealComponent.propTypes
  return {
    Picker
  }
})
```

Note that `@react-native-community/picker` is now [react-native-picker/picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker).

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#tips